# Validate fill Color of the element under SVG

Tags: java, selenium, svg, xpath, background-color

I am trying to validate the fill color of multiple elements on the page which are under SVG.  The Relative Xpath of these 7 elements are all the same.

//*[@id="svg_health-state-success"]/path

HTML

```
<div class="v-object-modifiers hide" xpath="1"> </div>
<svg role="img" class="c-icon c-icon-health-state-success" xpath="1"><use 
xlink:href="#svg_health-state-success"></use></svg>
<use xlink:href="#svg_health-state-success"></use>
<svg id="svg_health-state-success" viewBox="0 0 62.5 62.5" width="100%" 
height="100%"><path style="fill:#00a651" d="M0 0v62.5h62.5V0H0zm25.7 
48.2L9.5 32l8.6-8.6 7.8 8.4 20.9-17.4 6.2 6.4-27.3 27.4z"></path></svg>
<path style="fill:#00a651" d="M0 0v62.5h62.5V0H0zm25.7 48.2L9.5 32l8.6-8.6 
7.8 8.4 20.9-17.4 6.2 6.4-27.3 27.4z"></path>
</svg>
</use>
</svg>
</div>
```

I tried using the below on my script, it is not working

```
String XPATHONE = "//*[name()='svg']//*[name()='path' and @fill='#00a651' and position()=2]";
WebElement svgObj = driver.findElement(By.xpath(XPATHONE));
Actions actionBuilder = new Actions(driver);
actionBuilder.click(svgObj).build().perform();
```

Comment: you're looking for a path with an attribute named fill, you don't have any. You have paths with style attributes.

Comment: so how do i validate the style attribute of the path element ?

Comment: You might need `local-name()` instead of `name()`.

Answer (score 1):

`fill` is not an *attribute* of `path` element, but its *CSS style property*, so you cannot use `@fill` syntax. Try below XPath:

```
//*[name()='svg']//*[name()='path' and contains(@style, 'fill="#00a651"')]
```

Also I'm not sure about `position()=2` predicate as it doesn't seem that `path` node has any siblings (please update HTML source sample properly if it actually has siblings)